Why the expectation value of three currents is important in the anomaly?
I am studying the anomalies chapter (Chapter 30) of Schwartz's [Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model]. I want to ask why the expectation of three currents, $\langle J^\mu J^\nu J^\rho \rangle$, is important when we deal with the anomalies.
In his book, he deals with the neutral pion decay and the triangle diagram, first. Historically, it is one of the first detection of anomalies so I understand the importance of this argument. Later, he deals with Fujikawa's method that evaluates the transformation rule of the integral measure and it suggests $\partial_\mu J^{5\mu} = -\frac{e^2}{16\pi^2}F_{\mu\nu}\tilde F^{\mu\nu}$. In this derivation, we did not need to consider the triangle diagram or three currents. In the next section, he deals with gauge anomaly and the expectation value of three currents again. Using these three currents, he argues the anomaly constraints of the standard model. I want to understand the importance of three currents. Could you explain this importance?
Also, Eq. (30.72) of his textbook suggests the divergence of the conserved current of hypercharge and it says $\partial_\mu J^\mu_Y = (\sum_\text{left} Y_l^3 - \sum_\text{right} Y_r^3) \frac{g'^2}{32\pi^2} B_{\mu\nu}\tilde B^{\mu\nu}$. It seems that it has only a single current but why $Y^3$ appear? If you have some comments about this relation, it would be very helpful for me.

The expectation value of three currents is important because it's the first nontrivial expectation value in the computation of the anomaly, and it determines the whole thing.  Here's an illustration in the case of the chiral anomaly for one gauge field.  The anomaly describes how the action for the fermion sector varies as a function of the gauge fields.  Let $W[A]$ be the generating function of connected diagrams for the fermion sector; assuming the fermion measure transforms anomalously, we have
$$
 \delta_{\epsilon} W[A]
 =
 \int d^{4}x\, \epsilon^{a}\mathcal{A}_{a}
$$
where $\mathcal{A}_{a}$ is the anomaly, which is valued in the same group as $A$.  Integrating by parts, this equation lets us compute the anomaly in terms of variational derivatives of $W[A]$; in particular, we have
$$
-\mathcal{A}_{a}
=
\partial_{\mu} \frac{\delta W[A]}{\delta A^{a}_{\mu}} + g{f^{a}}_{bc}A^{b}_{\mu}\frac{\delta W[A]}{\delta A^{c}_{\mu}} 
$$
where ${f^{a}}_{bc}$ are the structure constants of the gauge group. And these are given by expectation values of currents:
$$
  \left.
  \frac{\delta^{n}W[A]}{\delta A^{a_{1}}_{\mu_{1}}(x_{1}) \dotsm \delta A^{a_{n}}_{\mu_{n}}(x_{n})}
  \right\rvert_{A = 0}
  =
  i^{n-1}
  \langle j^{\mu_{1}}_{a_{1}}(x_{1}) \dotsm j^{\mu_{n}}_{a_{n}}(x_{n})\rangle_{C}
$$
where the $C$ subscript is the connected part of the current expectation value.  This means that we can compute the anomaly $\mathcal{A}_{a}$ as a series in $A^{a}_{\mu}$ with coefficients given by connected current expectation values.  So let's consider these.
At zeroth order we have
$$
\mathcal{A}_{a}\rvert_{A = 0} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial z^{\mu}} \langle j^{\mu}_{a}(z)\rangle
$$
Since $\mathcal{A}_{a}$ is an integrand, if we assume that everything is vanishing at infinity we can ignore this term, giving $\mathcal{A}_{a} = \mathcal{O}(A)$.  At first order in $A^{a}_{\mu}$, Lorentz invariance requires
$$
\mathcal{A}_{a} = Z_{a} \partial^{\mu}A^{a}_{\mu} + \mathcal{O}(A^{2})
$$
for some constant tensor $Z_{a}$.  This is again a total derivative, so we can assume that $\mathcal{A}_{a} = \mathcal{O}(A^{2})$.  At second order, we have to do the three-current expectation value calculation you're asking about.  This is a lot of work, but when the dust clears we have
$$
\mathcal{A}_{a}
=
-\frac{g^{2}}{24\pi^{2}} d^{R}_{abc}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}(\partial_{\mu}A^{b}_{\nu})(\partial_{\alpha}A^{c}_{\beta}) + \mathcal{O}(A^{3})
$$
where $d^{R}_{abc}$ is an invariant of the representation in which the matter sector lives.  Since I skipped the calculation, I just want to emphasize that the non-trivial work so far consists of computing the expectation value for three currents.
The next step is the third order term, which can be computed in terms of a four-current expectation value.  But we can also appeal to symmetry considerations.  Since the anomaly violates chiral symmetry, it must include an $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}$, and since it only depends on $A^{a}_{\mu}$ and its derivatives, the most general possibility consistent with the mass dimension of the second order term is
$$
\mathcal{A}_{a}
=
-\frac{g^{2}}{24\pi^{2}}\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}\left( d^{R}_{abc}(\partial_{\mu}A^{b}_{\nu})(\partial_{\alpha}A^{c}_{\beta})
+
X_{abcd}A^{b}_{\mu}A^{c}_{\nu}\partial_{\alpha}A^{d}_{\beta}
+
Y_{abcde}A^{b}_{\mu}A^{c}_{\nu}A^{d}_{\alpha}A^{e}_{\beta}
\right)
$$
Perturbative gauge invariance requires that the BRST derivative of the anomaly vanish.  The BRST derivative of the $Y$ term is nonzero, and it can't be cancelled by the other terms, so we must have $Y = 0$.  Solving the BRST equation for $X$ then gives
$$
\mathcal{A}_{a}
=
-\frac{g^{2}}{24\pi^{2}}
d^{R}_{abc}
\epsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}
\partial_{\mu}\left(
A^{b}_{\nu}\partial_{\alpha}A^{c}_{\beta}
+
\frac{g}{4}
{f^{c}}_{de}
A^{b}_{\nu}A^{d}_{\alpha}A^{e}_{\beta}
\right)
$$
up to BRST-exact terms.  And this is the anomaly to all orders.
So if you think the anomaly is important, then you should also think that the expectation value of three currents is important.  A priori, the anomaly is a function of the expectation values of $n$ currents for all $n$.  We can ignore $n < 3$ for symmetry reasons.  And if we know $n = 3$, then symmetry considerations give the $n > 3$ rather easily.  So the calculation all comes down to the $n = 3$ case.
